# Conditional grouping with $exists inside $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two keys A and B and their existence in the document is mutually exclusive. I have to group by A when A exists and group by B when B exists. So I am `$project`ing the required value into a computed key called MyKey on which I'll perform a `$group`. But it looks like I'm making a mistake with the syntax. I tried writing $project in two ways:

```
{
  $project: {
    MyKey: {
      $cond: [{ $exists: ["$A", true] }, "$A", "$B"] }
    }
  }
```

and

```
{
  $project: {
    MyKey: {
      $cond: [{ "A": { $exists: true } }, "$A", "$B"] }
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting the error:

```json
{ 
  "errmsg": "exception: invalid operator '$exists'", 
  "code" : 15999, 
  "ok" : 0 
}
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use [`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) instead of `$cond` in your `$project`:

```js
{ $project: {MyKey: {$ifNull: ['$A', '$B'] }}}
```

If `A` exists and is not `null` its value will be used; otherwise the value of `B` is used.

Comment: can i use both $isNull and cond?

Comment: Note: If you don't want to set a field with the value `null` you can do something like:
`$ifNull: ["$field", newValue || "$field"],`
And if the `newValue` variable does not exist, it will not create the field.

Setting undefined still creates the object, that's why the solution works nicely :)

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to use $cond or $exisits an the $ifNull saved me.

Answer (score 73):

if one wants to check $exists with in $cond an alternative approach is to use $not
with $cond

```
{$project: {MyKey: {$cond: [{$not: ["$A"]}, "$B", "$A"]}}}
```

and truth table for $not is as

[image]

Hopes that Helps

Comment: Please be cautious before you use `$not` it basically converts falsy values into true & visa-versa, in case if you use it to check a field exists ({$not: ["$A"]}) then in that case, if your fields actual value is `0` then it would return `true`, where you'll be expecting trues for documents in which `A` field doesn't exist. Which is why this might not work in some cases !!

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me.  I had to also check for null in case the field existed but was null:
{ "$and" : [{ "$not" : ["$MyKey"] }, { "MyKey" : null }] }

Answer (score 25):

You can simulate exists with

```
$ne : [$var_to_check, undefined]
```

This returns true if the var is defined

Comment: In Java there is a `BsonUndefined` sub type for `BsonValue`

Comment: Hmm not working for me

Comment: Solution above doesn't work for me, I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720905/6529932, which works.

Answer (score 11):

Some sharing that i found in $cond and check is existing:

```
$cond: {
  if: "$A1",
  then: "$A1",
  else: "$B1"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

A strict equivalent of what could be expected of `{ k: { $exists: true } }` in an aggregation or `$expr` statement can be achieved with:
`{ $or: ['$k', { $in: ['$k', [null, 0, false]] }] }`

**Explanation:**

Comparison of a field value with `null` using `$eq` or `$in` is strict and would return false if field is not set.

The truth table for these is the following

```
                        | null  | unset | truthy | falsy |
------------------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
{ $eq: ['$k', null] }   | TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE  | FALSE |
{ $in: ['$k', [null]] } | TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE  | FALSE |
```

So, to know when a field is set, we have to toggle *truthy* and *falsy* columns of the table to `true`.

Truthy values are… well, truthy, so we can use them as-is: `{ $or: ['$k', { $eq: ['$k', null] }] }`

In MongoDB, falsy values are `0`, `false` and `null` so we can add the missing ones to our `$in` clause: `{ $in: ['$k', [null, 0, false]] }`

By merging these, we obtain `{ $or: ['$k', { $in: ['$k', [null, 0, false]] }] }` which will now return `true` if the field is either truthy, `0`, `false` or `null` and `false` if unset.

Answer (score 1):

I found your questions while looking for a similar problem, but insted of a key, I was looking for my parameters. I finally solved the issue.

This is what I used for my *$_id.status* parameter, to check that if it exists inside the cond.

```
$cond: [{
     $or: [{
          $ne: ["$_id.status", null]
     }]
}, 1, null]
```

*$or* is not needed. I keep it there... just for fun. I don't think it affects the query that much for the moment. I will test the speed later.