# How can I sort field if another filed is not null?

Tags: mongodb

How can I sort field if another filed is not null? I have data like the following and I want sort by pinOrder, pin, created. But I want to sort based on `pinOrder` only `pin` field not null, If `pin` field is null, just sort data by `created`.

Can this be solved by an aggregation pipeline?

```json
[
  {
    "id": "62b9c1d74321afff4cb4e652",
    "created": "2022-06-27T14:42:31.726Z",
    "pin": "2022-06-27T14:42:31.703Z",
    "pin_order": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "62b55d6ee0e1fa12861f8cb8",
    "created": "2022-06-24T06:45:02.126Z",
    "pin": null,
    "pin_order": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "629a212eda64722e286d29f6",
    "created": "2022-06-03T14:56:46.980Z",
    "pin": null,
    "pin_order": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB sort by field A if field B != null otherwise sort by field C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810712/mongodb-sort-by-field-a-if-field-b-null-otherwise-sort-by-field-c)

Comment: guess all `filed` should be `field`

Comment: One thing to note is that pin_order is a number whereas created is a date. How do you want to handle this? First all items where pin is not null by pin_order, then all items where pin is null by created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be solved using an aggregation pipeline. If you want to retrieve pinned items first, followed by the rest in order of creation, you can use the following pipeline ([playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mti5YS60xRl)):

```
[
  {
    $set: {
      "sortField": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $ne: [
              "$pin",
              null
            ]
          },
          then: "$pin_order",
          else: 9999999
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortField: 1,
      created: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "sortField"
  }
]
```

This pipeline creates an artificial field for sorting; if an item is pinned, the `pin_order` value is used, otherwise a value with a high number (higher than the expected `pin_order` values) is used so that all items that are not pinned will be added after the pinned items.

You could optimize this by using a high number as default for the `pin_order` field instead of 1 as in your sample data. Then there is no need for an aggregation pipeline and you can sort the data directly. As soon as an item is pinned, you assign a lower value to the `pin_order` property.

Comment: Thank you, I think `else: 999999` can be replace with `else : "$$REMOVE"`.

Comment: @user10965730 you're welcome. If you use `$$REMOVE`, the without a pin date will not include the `sortField`. When sorting, this is considered as an empty value and the order is changed - the not pinned documents come first. As far as I understand your requirements, the pinned items should come first. In this case I'd propse to use the large number to put the items without a pin after the ones that have bin pinned.